# Check the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+nx)^{n}}{n!}$ at $x= \frac{1}{e}$

Tags: calculus

Check the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+nx)^{n}}{n!}$ at $x= \frac{1}{e}$

By using D 'Alembert's ratio test, the series is convergent for  $x< \frac{1}{e}$ and divergent for  $x> \frac{1}{e}$

At $x= \frac{1}{e}$

$\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \dfrac{(n+1)(1+ \dfrac ne)^n}{(1+\dfrac{n+1}e)(1+\dfrac{n+1}e)^n}$

I tried logarithmic test.
But calculations became complicated.

Any suggestion$?$

Comment: How can it be convergent for the larger values of $x$ ??? And how is this clear ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust, I mistyped the question. Now I've edited it.

Comment: Yep, but "unclearness" is still there.

Comment: By using D 'Alembert's ratio test.

Comment: I know but the bound $1/e$ is far from being immediately visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $(1+nx)^{n} >\frac {n^{n}} {e^{n}}$ and  use Stirling's Formula. Since $\sum \frac  1 {\sqrt n}$ diverges the given series also diverges.